# Postgres concurrent transactions per connection

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, postgresql, jdbc

I am reading about `number of concurrent transaction per connection`.

I came across [jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/91/thread](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/91/thread.html).
It says

> If a thread attempts to use the connection while another one is using it, it will wait until the other thread has finished its current operation.

So based on above if i have a connection pool of 1 connection(using `cp03`) 
and in one thread i do:

```
start transaction
Read query
sleep for 2 min
commit transaction
```

**Then other thread should not be able to run any query until the first thread completes the transaction... right ?**

But in my observation i was able to have other thread complete transaction while first thread is sleeping

Why is that?  what am i missing ?

EDIT:
CP03 configuration:

```
        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />                                               
        <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="1" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="0" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="0" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="100" />
```

Comment: want to post your cp03 configuration

Comment: @ScaryWombat added config

Answer (score 0):

The keyword here is `wait`. What happens when there is a lock, a `wait` and the thread that holds the lock goes to `sleep` or `yield`s? Now the other thread is able to make use of the connection.